# Searching for .htaccess on Apple Mac

Tags: .htaccess, mamp

I know this question has been asked many times, and i have looked through many of the forum answers but:
After using terminal to retrieve hidden documents I still cannot find .htaccess file. I have also used text wrangler and when i went to open and typed the name in, there was no .htaccess.
Therefore, am i missing a trick? Do i need to create one?
I have found the section to change in apache>http.conf. I do not want the php file to be found if they type in the URL, instead i want users to only access it via a login page.
Any help is much appreciated.

```
#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Order allow,deny
Allow from all

</Directory>

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

<IfModule perl_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.pl
</IfModule>

<IfModule wsgi_module>

DirectoryIndex index.wsgi index.py
</IfModule>

</IfModule>

#  
# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride 
# directive.
#
    AccessFileName .htaccess

    #
    # The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being  
    # viewed by Web clients.  
    #
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>

<Files ~ "^\.DS_Store">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>


 <Files login.php>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: .htaccess files are not a default file in any directory. The use of one is optional so if you want it you have to create the file and then turn on `AllowOverride All` in the config.

Comment: @PanamaJack Thanks for that, i have attached the conf file and also part of the .htaccess file at the bottom. I am able to block or filter which php files I want to be seen etc. But I want to prevent users from accessing the file but directly typing the URL, and instead access it from the login.php page. Therefore i don't want them to be completely blocked but users cannot just type in the URL. Any ideas of how to do that with the .htaccess? I know there are a few comments on here but answers seem to vary a lot.